# New applications open behind active Safari window

Tags: macos

For the past week or two, whenever I try to open a new application (like Preview or System Preferences) while on Safari, it always opens behind it, leaving the active window on top.

I might be wrong, but I'm pretty sure when you open a new program it used to appear on top.

Is there any way to get that back? I've looked at System Preferences and I haven't been able to find anything that works.

Comment: I amend my question -- new applications only stay behind Safari. They'll appear up over stuff like Pages and App Store. Also, I don't use Spaces, like, ever.

Comment: Have you rebooted?

Comment: @Ryan re "I amend my question" Please edit the question and not leave a comment

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. When you are using Safari, how do you launch the other app? From the Dock? Using Spotlight? By any other means?

Comment: Yeah, I just open it in by clicking the app in the Dock.